# Remove columns where a value count satisfies a condition (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df in the format below with ~70000 columns and 540 rows. All values are either 0.0, 0.5, or 1.0.

```
 VAR         1_139632_G  1_158006_T  1_172595_A  1_564650_A  1_564652_G  \
 SRR4216489         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5   
 SRR4216786         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5   
 SRR4216628         0.5         0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0   
 SRR4216456         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5   
 SRR4216393         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5
```

I would like to remove all columns where the number of '0.5' values is only 1 less than the number of rows. SO far I have tried;

```
total_samples = len(df.index) # Gets the number of rows
df_col_05 = df[df == 0.5].count() # returns a df with column-wise counts
df_col_05 = df_col_05.where(df_col_05 < (total_samples-1)) #replaces with Nan where the condition isn't met
```

what I want is my original df to have all cols removed where the value of df_col_05 is >= (total_samples-1), so basically remove wherever 'df_col_05' has an NaN but am not sure how to do this?

I'm sure this should be easy for anyone with a bit more pandas experience than myself (I started a few days ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filtering columns, also better is use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) for get `size` of `True`s in `DataFrame`:

```
#if first column is not index set it
df = df.set_index('VAR')
df1 = df.loc[:, (df == 0.5).sum() >= len(df.index)-1]
```

**Sample**:

```
#changed values in last 2 columns
print (df)
          VAR  1_139632_G  1_158006_T  1_172595_A  1_564650_A  1_564652_G
0  SRR4216489         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.0         0.0
1  SRR4216786         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.0         0.5
2  SRR4216628         0.5         0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
3  SRR4216456         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5
4  SRR4216393         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5

print (df[df == 0.5].count())
VAR           0
1_139632_G    5
1_158006_T    4
1_172595_A    4
1_564650_A    2
1_564652_G    3
dtype: int64

print ((df == 0.5).sum())
VAR           0
1_139632_G    5
1_158006_T    4
1_172595_A    4
1_564650_A    2
1_564652_G    3
dtype: int64
```

---

```
#if first column is not index set it
df = df.set_index('VAR')

print ((df == 0.5).sum() >= len(df.index)-1)
1_139632_G     True
1_158006_T     True
1_172595_A     True
1_564650_A    False
1_564652_G    False
dtype: bool

print (df.loc[:, (df == 0.5).sum() >= len(df.index)-1])
            1_139632_G  1_158006_T  1_172595_A
VAR                                           
SRR4216489         0.5         0.5         0.5
SRR4216786         0.5         0.5         0.5
SRR4216628         0.5         0.0         1.0
SRR4216456         0.5         0.5         0.5
SRR4216393         0.5         0.5         0.5
```

Another solution without `set_index`, only is necessary define columns which always need in output:

```
m = (df == 0.5).sum() >= len(df.index)-1
print (m)
VAR           False
1_139632_G     True
1_158006_T     True
1_172595_A     True
1_564650_A    False
1_564652_G    False
dtype: bool

need_cols = ['VAR']
m.loc[need_cols] = True
print (m)
VAR            True
1_139632_G     True
1_158006_T     True
1_172595_A     True
1_564650_A    False
1_564652_G    False
dtype: bool

print (df.loc[:, m])
          VAR  1_139632_G  1_158006_T  1_172595_A
0  SRR4216489         0.5         0.5         0.5
1  SRR4216786         0.5         0.5         0.5
2  SRR4216628         0.5         0.0         1.0
3  SRR4216456         0.5         0.5         0.5
4  SRR4216393         0.5         0.5         0.5
```

Similar solution is filtering columns separately and then select:

```
print (df[df.columns[m]])
          VAR  1_139632_G  1_158006_T  1_172595_A  1_564652_G
0  SRR4216489         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.0
1  SRR4216786         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5
2  SRR4216628         0.5         0.0         1.0         0.0
3  SRR4216456         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5
4  SRR4216393         0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5
```

Comment: Great! that solves it - many thanks! As I'm a pandas newb do you mind to clarify what a few bits of the code are doing. Is this "df.loc[:," making it point to all columns and across all rows at the same time? I presume it requires a size matched boolean array with a shared index which is where 'm' comes in?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Classic boolean indexing is simplier and remove rows by boolean mask like `df=df[df['col'] < 5]`. But for removing columns need loc, first `:` means all rows and then boolean mask remove columns by condition. And is necessary same size of mask as df, else raise error. So good luck with pandas and if need something explain more, let me know. Nice weekend!